# Fetch third Level Depth Data from taxonomy with performance

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, performance

I have taxonomy with 4 Level **State->District->Block->Villages**. I want to get all villages of all Blocks of all Districts of a State.

I have done it by loops but my performance is very slow. please help me this take more time than expectation and very slow process.

[image]

Comment: What do you need to do with those 650.000 items? I suppose your are not showing all that items in the resulting page. If you explain why do you need them is easier to solve your problem.

Comment: I have a Content Type for Village Data Where store particular State->District->Block->Village Data. I want to show records based on filters. I have a Role Village Auditor that check data by state and village auditor want to check how many Village Entries in particular State.

Comment: This doesn't explain whay you need to load all Villages at the same time. Why don't you use Views?

Comment: i want to show add count for all village have any entry or not..

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all child at any level by using this code :

```
function taxonomy_get_children_all($tid, $vid = 0, $key = 'tid'){
  $c = taxonomy_get_children($tid, $vid, $key);
  $result = array();
  foreach ($c as $t => $d){
    $result[$t] = $d;
    $below = taxonomy_get_children_all($t, $vid, $key);
    if (!empty($below)) {
      $result[$t]->children = array();
      foreach ($below as $nt => $nd){
        $result[$t]->children[$nt] = $nd;
      }
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

OR

You can do it by adding custom database query using function [function taxonomy_get_children](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/7)

Comment: I have also get by this function by it's very slow process because i have 6.5 lacs villages, 65 thousand blocks etc. thanks for your reply

Comment: when you have lots of data they system take some time to collect information

Comment: this is the main issue. performance for collecting data